# What are the meaning and structure of "leaders also are viewed as conflict averse over concerns"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

http://freebeacon.com/national-security/chinas-powerful-general-xi-jinping-henchman-meets-mattis/

> PLA leaders also are viewed as conflict averse over concerns any major conflict would cost the lives of their sole sons or daughters—an outgrowth of the decades long Chinese population control policies.

---

relatives: [What's the structure of the sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/172083/whats-the-structure-of-the-sentence)

Comment: What do you not understand? to be [noun] over something.

Comment: It might be easier to read if it was properly punctuated as **conflict-averse** (that is, averse to conflict).

Comment: @Lambie I didn't understand "someone is viewed as conflict averse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...concerns [that] any major conflict...

...[which is] an outgrowth...

**over concerns** = because of concerns

**over** introduces the *basis* for an emotion in this usage:

> He is upset over the accident.

The phrase **conflict-averse** means "averse to conflict", i.e. wanting to avoid conflict.

"conflict-averse over concerns" is awkward.

**over** should be **because** or **inasmuch as** or any other phrase that indicates cause-and-effect.

> ... they are conflict-averse because they fear any major conflict
>   would cost the lives of their sole sons or daughters

Comment: What's the meaning of "conflict averse"?

Comment: I was typing as you were commenting :)